# Does anyone have experience with the AMD/Intel server vendor Iron Systems?

Tags: hardware

I am obviously looking into the big player (IBM, HP, Dell, Sun, Etc...) however I was poking around and liked them not only for cost (albeit a big factor regarding my interest) was that I was able to configure it just right and the had the same warranty/on site options the big guys have (specifically 24/7 4 hour). But, they could end up being out of business in a years time (especially when you consider the economy). So if anyone could shed some light on the subject it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of easy sources of information you can check to learn this sort of information for yourself. Here are just some of the quickest ones to check:

Check out their company history page to find out how long they've been in the business, and who their main clients are: (http://www.ironsystems.com/aboutus-ourhistory.asp)

Look up news stories relating to the company on a news aggregator (like google news). You will see any large scale successes or failures as news recorded in multiple sources, as well as any large rounds of funding, mergers, acquisitions, etc... Also look for any well publicized charity related, or event sponsorship, activities - companies which aren't doing well, can't afford to participate in large charity events.

Ask them to provide you with references. If they've been around for a while, they should have clients that are willing to speak with you and answer any questions you might have about the business.